How long will it take for every node in a graph to be selected?
This problem has been really confusing me lately. Suppose I have a graph like this (each node represents a person and the people that they communicate with):

Imagine the following process:

iteration 1: a random person ("A") in this network has an "idea"
iteration 2: "A" communicates his idea to all his (1st degree) neighbors (let's call this set of neighbors as "B")
iteration 3: Everyone in "B" communicates with all their (1st degree) neighbors (let's call this set of neighbors as "C")
iteration 4: Everyone in "C" communicates with all their (1st degree) neighbors (let's call this set as "D")
etc

I tried to visually represent this process below (white refers to nodes not actively involved in the communication, yellow are nodes passing the message and blue are nodes receiving the message):

My question is the following : In general (i.e. for a very large graph), at some future iteration, will every node on the graph actively be involved in communication (i.e. either passing the message or receiving the message)? Does that mean that at a future iteration, there will be no white nodes left in the network?

This is called connectivity of a graph. If there is a path from each node to each node, eventually there will be no white nodes.

@ van der wolf: thank you for replying ... just to clarify ... i mean that : at iteration 99 for example, will the nodes actively be communicating and there will be no silent nodes?

I am not referring to nodes that communicated in the past ... but nodes that are actively communicating at the current iteration. will nodes actively be participating in the communication at the current iteration?

Try to look at the binary rooted tree where the initial active cell is the root...

Every node, once "contacted" will continue to either be sending or receiving communication because:

The node being contacted means that it has a neighbor from which the communication has emanated
On next iteration, the said node will communicate back to the sender (and potentially more)
The neighbor will send back to "this" node
2-3 repeats

As long as every node has eventual connection with every other node (i.e. the graph is connected), every node will eventually either be sending or receiving communication, therefore "no white nodes," per your vocabulary.
In fact, the above properties of nodes ensure that the first iteration at which all nodes are involved in communication is precisely the maximum distance between the original sender and any node (since such node will be the "last" to be involved in communication).

Here's probably a way to argue.
First of all, your graph has to be connected. Now notice that any vertex that get's coloured, will always stay coloured. Also notice that at every stage, the blue vertices become yellow and the yellow vertices become blue. Now all we have to show is that this process always increases the pool of coloured vertices whenever there is some white vertex.
Suppose not. That is, at some iteration, there are white vertices and no new vertex gets coloured. Note that your process has stalled. At no further stage can white vertices be coloured. Suppose $v$ is one such vertex. Then $v$ cannot have any yellow neighbor since then $v$ would have been coloured, and it cannot have any blue neighbor because in the next stage, it would become coloured.
But then the same argument holds for the neighbors of $v$ twice separated. Now since your graph is connected, there is a path from $v$ to your initial yellow vertex. But then arguing as above, this initial vertex $A$ must be white. A contradiction.

Here's the same argument, but phrased differently. Pick any vertex $v$. Since your graph is connected, there is a path from $A$ to $v$. Note that the next vertex in the path after $A$ gets coloured after the first iteration, the second one after $A$ gets coloured in the second iteration and so on. Eventually, $v$ gets coloured (and at this point, all the vertices in the path are also coloured, since coloured vertices never become white). Thus at some point, every vertex get's coloured since every vertex lies in some path from $A$.

In fact, the second proof tells you how long it will take. It will take exactly $\max_{v\in V}d(A,v)$ iterations, where $d(u,v)$  is the length of the shortest path between $u$ and $v$.
